# Clustering lat/long data points that are very close to each other

Tags: python, algorithm, k-means, dbscan

I have a fairly small dataset (only 138 observations) that are all very close to each other geographically. I would like to create clusters from this data.

The requirements fro my clusters would be:

- hopefully between 10-12 clusters overall of around 10-12 locations in each
- within a geographical distance of say 5km-10km from each other

I have tried to techniques

KMeans with the number of clusters set to 12. This gave decent results, but I also know that KMeans is not right for lat/long data.

I am trying dbscan, but I think I am hitting an issue where the dataset is simply too small. This only outputs one cluster group for all of my observations.

In [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/354283016_How_can_Small_Data_Sets_be_Clustered) paper I see it mentioned that dbscan gives nonsensical results in such a small set.

I want to create these clusters with a better approach than KMeans and want to know if I am missing something in my code or if there is a better approach to take here

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from geopy.distance import great_circle
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
coords = pd.read_csv("locs.csv")
coords1 = coords.to_numpy()
kms_per_radian = 6371.0088
max_distance = 5
epsilon = max_distance/kms_per_radian
db = DBSCAN(eps=epsilon, min_samples=5,  algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine').fit(np.radians(coords1))
cluster_labels = db.labels_
num_clusters = len(set(cluster_labels))
clusters = pd.Series([coords[cluster_labels == n] for n in range(num_clusters)])
print('Number of clusters: {}'.format(num_clusters))
```

here is my data - sorry if it shows up sloppily. it getsread in a locs.csv here

```
lat long
33.1176813  -96.6889152
33.1311714  -96.6673619
33.0960563  -96.6961237
33.1453321  -96.6842826
33.1391395  -96.6758389
33.0971504  -96.6870497
33.1262443  -96.6878928
33.1143839  -96.6945359
33.114209   -96.6945359
33.1149433  -96.6927684
33.109267   -96.6937003
33.1331405  -96.6666864
33.1383939  -96.6680508
33.1472743  -96.688812
33.1057274  -96.680582
33.1368991  -96.6796421
33.107386   -96.678968
33.150424   -96.6965207
33.1279273  -96.6806465
33.1087588  -96.6876371
33.1262534  -96.6742925
33.098562   -96.6853026
33.1125942  -96.6883732
33.1102927  -96.6961864
33.1035043  -96.6955179
33.1243762  -96.6788757
33.1291342  -96.677637
33.1156607  -96.6858248
33.093478   -96.6997758
33.1260525  -96.6890209
33.0916379  -96.6965207
33.1283669  -96.6724685
33.1033839  -96.6874843
33.1483239  -96.6828948
33.157496   -96.684684
33.0956047  -96.6976071
33.0956047  -96.6976071
33.1057274  -96.680582
33.1574837  -96.6850944
33.1582715  -96.6965416
33.1386326  -96.6783054
33.158112   -96.684861
33.138768   -96.675811
33.098562   -96.6853026
33.1030668  -96.6955179
33.107386   -96.678968
33.1379475  -96.6698679
33.1117192  -96.6878473
33.0926369  -96.691028
33.092519   -96.6948466
33.1542432  -96.6823992
33.1542432  -96.6823992
33.1330701  -96.6743789
33.1309656  -96.6879346
33.1469985  -96.6874333
33.1454754  -96.6839861
33.1261935  -96.6725202
33.1566998  -96.6841281
33.1566998  -96.6841281
33.107347   -96.6921094
33.107147   -96.6817192
33.1081097  -96.6880473
33.1243427  -96.6773343
33.1294931  -96.685219
33.1089024  -96.6894143
33.1348689  -96.6686227
33.125196   -96.6825663
33.1239856  -96.6892297
33.1549715  -96.6965207
33.1033242  -96.6887841
33.098562   -96.6853026
33.1360933  -96.67346
33.1081031  -96.6886583
33.1552268  -96.69299
33.1323984  -96.6658496
33.1262448  -96.6740307
33.1257552  -96.6869133
33.1257552  -96.6869133
33.1143839  -96.6945359
33.126066   -96.692029
33.1374841  -96.6677798
33.1405272  -96.6739612
33.1129799  -96.6893467
33.1320952  -96.6811459
33.1239267  -96.6899191
33.1252 -96.6837151
33.1033242  -96.6887841
33.1123512  -96.6774962
33.103736   -96.6867271
33.094192   -96.7010288
33.1392404  -96.6783889
33.1527167  -96.683548
33.1129669  -96.6826289
33.1193324  -96.6887284
33.1519071  -96.6921126
33.1358899  -96.6758085
33.1358899  -96.6758085
33.0987211  -96.6966042
33.1226774  -96.6762474
33.0968079  -96.6967923
33.1393173  -96.6642923
33.108696   -96.6970012
33.1078495  -96.6846551
33.1243762  -96.6788757
33.1243762  -96.6788757
33.1518825  -96.6811668
33.1239576  -96.6921962
33.1483239  -96.6828948
33.1125542  -96.6792695
33.1517525  -96.6835898
33.1145307  -96.6889703
33.1235157  -96.6751516
33.1549715  -96.6965207
33.1041763  -96.6868112
33.1352762  -96.6691161
33.1311522  -96.6726246
33.1526416  -96.6857622
33.1391395  -96.6758389
33.114209   -96.6945359
33.1343714  -96.6649288
33.1243142  -96.6937003
33.1343154  -96.6788902
33.0914204  -96.6888572
33.1087365  -96.6946195
33.1087365  -96.6946195
33.1123452  -96.6715541
33.1453321  -96.6842826
33.1573651  -96.6865559
33.1302622  -96.6730521
33.1549715  -96.6965207
33.1266383  -96.6807078
33.1091322  -96.6884788
33.114369   -96.6825872
33.1512367  -96.68994
33.126426   -96.6910263
33.1117173  -96.6940972
33.1117173  -96.6940972
33.1061857  -96.6810057
```

Comment: First, make a scatterplot. If the clusters are not clearly separated from each other, then DBSCAN will not work.

Comment: In reality I figured that was the case - that’s why I put “small data set, close together” I think my kmeans also works much better comparatively. Thanks for replying. Although I also tried expanding the size of the geographic area in question in relation to the Earth's circumference, and this helped to increase the clustering in dbscan. But in reality, KMeans produced more reliable, understandable results.

Comment: Convert your `[lat, long]` coordinates to 3D `[x,y,z]` tuples, then run k-means over those tuples.

Comment: I actually did exactly that - and got very good clusters